# Android SpeechRecognizer ERROR_NETWORK

Tags: android, google-play, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am currently working on an app that uses the `SpeechRecognizer` but I keep getting error 2 which is `ERROR_NETWORK`.
When looking into the logs I can see the following:

```
01-19 14:38:00.080   1291-13267/? W/JavaNetConnection﹕ Failed to get connection status.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/m/voice-search/down?pair=760f1fd2-4b87-48b8-bf6f-76cfc79d8ae8
        at kxb.getInputStream(PG:228)
        at kxa.getInputStream(PG:210)
        at kxc.getInputStream(PG:25)
        at cla.Gj(PG:256)
        at dzz.Gj(PG:26)
        at cla.Gi(PG:240)
        at cla.disconnect(PG:132)
        at clb.b(PG:110)
        at clb.a(PG:66)
        at dzb.a(PG:197)
        at cqj.HS(PG:529)
        at cqi.run(PG:314)
```

The way I use my `SpeechRecognizer` is

```
private void setupVoiceRecorder() {
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new Listener());
}
```

and then I start recording like so:

```
private void startVoiceRecording(String languageKey) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                      RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    String packageName = getPackageName();
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, packageName);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, languageKey);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
}
```

The thing is that sometimes it works. But in most cases it fails...
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: maybe sometimes the internet is not available? Speech Recognizer works online...

Comment: So, you read the error and saw the FileNotFoundException. If I had to guess what you're doing wrong, it's using an invalid file.

Comment: Seems as if that's a bug in the Google-App for Android (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=100389)